# Proper idHTTP proxy support implementation

Tags: delphi, proxy, indy

Can anyone please verify if this is the correct way to use an HTTPS proxy with Indy's HTTP component and also if SOCKS support is correct too? I'd like to add support for them both however I'm more familiar with ICS than I am Indy. Thanks!

```
var
  sData: TMemoryStream;
  HTTP: TidHTTP;
  SSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  socks: TidSocksInfo;
begin
  sData := TMemoryStream.Create();
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  Socks := TIdSocksInfo.Create(nil);
try
  HTTP.IOHandler := SSL;
  HTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
  HTTP.ReadTimeout := 60000;
  HTTP.ConnectTimeout := 5000;
  if (SOCKS_PROXY) then
  begin
  SSL.TransparentProxy := Socks;
  Socks.Host := '66.33.114.72';
  Socks.Port := 8080;
  // if Auth then specifiy credentials
  Socks.Username := 'username';
  Socks.Password := 'password';
  end;
  if (HTTP_PROXY) then
  begin
  HTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := '127.0.0.1';
  HTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 8080;
  // if Auth then specifiy credentials
  HTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyUsername := 'username';
  HTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyPassword := 'password';
  end;
  HTTP.Get(sURL, sData);
  result := (HTTP.ResponseCode = 200) and (sData.Size > 0);
  if (result) then
  sData.SaveToFile(sFileName);
finally
  FreeAndNil(sData);
  FreeAndNil(HTTP);
  FreeAndNil(SSL);
  FreeAndNil(Socks);
end;
end;
```

Comment: Very close. For SOCKS, you are not specifying a protocol version to activate the `TIdSocksInfo` so it will actually connect to the proxy

Comment: Thanks, it's working for me now. Last question Remy, do you have to set HTTP.ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication to true when using the HTTP proxy option that's built in to idHTTP? I'm not sure if I should set it or not.

Comment: that depends on whether the HTTP proxy supports `BASIC` authentication or not. Setting `BasicAuthentication=True` essential forces `BASIC` as a fallback even if the proxy doesn't suppprt it.